# Is there an evolutionary reason for the 5 electron transport complexes in plants and animals?

Tags: evolution, metabolism, photosynthesis, cellular-respiration

The electron transport chains of both the light reactions of photosynthesis (in plants) and oxidative phosphorylation (in animals) *both contain 5 complexes* including ATP synthase, as shown below.

[image: Oxidative phosphorylation]
[Image Source](http://prodomweb.univ-lyon1.fr/priam/REL_JUL03/RALSTO_ALL/PRIAM_REPLICON/RES_PRIAM/map00190_org.html)

[image: Light Reaction]
[Image Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Thylakoid_membrane.png)

Is this coincidence, or does this possibly suggest that both chloroplast and mitochondrion precursors derived their energy-obtaining mechanisms via an ancient evolutionarily-related metabolic pathway which diverged?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your latter assumption is the best we have so far, to my understanding.

Here are a few excerpts from ["Early Evolution of Photosynthesis"](http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/154/2/434.full) published in *Plant Physiology*, October 2010 (emphasis mine):

> There is suggestive evidence that photosynthetic organisms were present **approximately 3.2 to 3.5 billion years ago...**
>
> Overwhelming evidence indicates that eukaryotic photosynthesis originated from endosymbiosis of **cyanobacterial-like organisms**, which ultimately became chloroplasts (Margulis, 1992). So the evolutionary origin of photosynthesis is to be found in the bacterial domain.

And then there's the abstract from this paper: ["Do photosynthetic and respiratory electron-transport chains share redox proteins?"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/096800049090296N)

> In purple nonsulfur bacteria and cyanobacteria, **there is close interaction between the photosynthetic and respiratory electron-transport chains, which share identical redox proteins.**

Purple bacteria and cyanobacteria are some of the oldest known lineages (>3BY, whereas Mitochondria parallel Eukaryotic origins at about 1.4BY - and the endosymbiosis which created Chloroplasts probably came after [plants have *both* Chloroplasts **and** Mitochondria, whereas most Eukaryotes just have Mitochondria]), and since the respiratory chain and photosynthetic chain share identical proteins in cyanobacteria and purple bacteria it's not a huge leap to assume that - yup - the 5-protein structure is probably the template used by both Chloroplasts and Mitochondria because of a common source.

Comment: The second paper and associated paragraph is EXACTLY what I was looking for. +1, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the [endosymbiosis theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endosymbiotic_theory) both mitochondria and chloroplasts derive from ancestral bacteria that invaded/were phagocytosed (fancy word for eaten) by eukaryotic cells.

So, the electron transport chains of both mitochondria and chloroplasts would indeed share a common bacterial ancestor.